# How to unite two different structures into one array and sort it? Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm building a feed, where I want to unite two different structures and sort the feed by date, here's how I've tried. It shows mistakes in View. It writes either "compiler unable to type check in reasonable time", either something else that connects to the `ForEach` loop.
Maybe you have an idea what can be an issue? Or, if there's other way to build and sort the feed?

**EDIT**: The following **error**: "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

```
class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var feed: [FeedCommonContent] = []

// download(ed) articles
self.feed.append(Article(id: doc.document.documentID, title: title, pic: pic, time: time.dateValue(), user: user))

// download(ed) tutorials
self.feed.append(Tutorial(id: doc.document.documentID, title: title, steps: [steps], notes: notes, pic: pic, time: time.dateValue(), user: user))

// sort the feed
self.feed.sort { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
    return p1.time > p2.time
}

    
}


protocol FeedCommonContent {
    // Define anything in common between objects
    var time: Date { get set }
    var id: String { get set }
    var feedIdentity: FeedIdentity.RawValue { get } // Article, or Tutorial; or - { get set }
}

enum FeedIdentity: String {
    // case Article, Tutorial
    case Article = "Article"
    case Tutorial = "Tutorial"
    
}



struct Article: Identifiable, FeedCommonContent {
    var feedIdentity = FeedIdentity.Article.rawValue
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var pic: String
    var time: Date
    var user: User
}

struct Tutorial: Identifiable, FeedCommonContent {
    var feedIdentity = FeedIdentity.Tutorial.rawValue
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var titleImage: String
    var name: String
    var user: User
    var inventory: [String]
    var steps: [String]
    var notes: String
    var time: Date
    var warnings: String
}
```

```
struct FeedView: View {
    
    @StateObject var feedData = FeedViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {

            ForEach(feedData.feed, id: \.self.id) { item in
                            
                // also tried type checking:
                // if item is Article // or, if let article = item as? Article
                if item.feedIdentity == FeedIdentity.Article.rawValue {

                    NavigationLink(destination: ArticleView(article: item, articleData: feedData)) {
                        ArticleUnitView(article: item, feedData: feedData)
                    }
                                
                 } else if item.feedIdentity == FeedIdentity.Tutorial.rawValue { //  if item is Tutorial

                     NavigationLink(destination: TutorialView(tutorial: item, feedData: feedData)) {
                         TutorialUnitView(tutorial: item, feedData: feedData)
                     }
                                
                 }
        }
    }
```

When I did an array only of one of data structures, all worked. (i.e. either `var articles: [Article] = []`, or `var tutorials: [Tutorial] = []` etc..)

Comment: Can you update your question to include what `FeedCommonContent`, `Article` and `Tutorial` are?

Comment: You have created an enum but you are not using it properly IMO, you shouldn’t use the raw value but instead the enum directly. So for instance change the protocol to use `var feedIdentity: FeedIdentity { get }`. And I can’t see any reason for the enum to even have a raw value based on the posted code.

Comment: good point about the enum, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hey, agree. I’ve tried it first and then I’ve started to try everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the (test) code I used to show how to "sort" your feed by date, and display it in a View:

EDIT, using "Joakim Danielson" enum suggestion:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            FeedView()
        }
    }
}

class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var feed: [FeedCommonContent] = []
    
    // for testing
    init() {
        self.feed.append(Article(title: "article title", pic: "pic1", time: Date(), user: User()))
        self.feed.append(Tutorial(titleImage: "title1", name: "tut1", user: User(), inventory: [], steps: [], notes: "note1", time: Date(), warnings: ""))
        sortFeed()
    }
    
    func sortFeed() {
        feed.sort { $0.time > $1.time }
    }
}

protocol FeedCommonContent {
    // Define anything in common between objects
    var time: Date { get set }
    var id: String { get set }
    var feedIdentity: FeedIdentity { get } // Article, or Tutorial; or - { get set }
}

enum FeedIdentity: String {
    // case Article, Tutorial
    case Article 
    case Tutorial   
}

struct User: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String = "user"
}

struct Article: Identifiable, FeedCommonContent {
    let feedIdentity = FeedIdentity.Article
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var pic: String
    var time: Date
    var user: User
}

struct Tutorial: Identifiable, FeedCommonContent {
    let feedIdentity = FeedIdentity.Tutorial
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var titleImage: String
    var name: String
    var user: User
    var inventory: [String]
    var steps: [String]
    var notes: String
    var time: Date
    var warnings: String
}

struct FeedView: View {
    
    @StateObject var feedData = FeedViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(feedData.feed, id: \.id) { item in
                
//                switch item.feedIdentity {
//                case FeedIdentity.Article:
//                    NavigationLink(destination: ArticleView(article: item, articleData: feedData)) {
//                        ArticleUnitView(article: item, feedData: feedData)
//                    }
//                case FeedIdentity.Tutorial:
//                    NavigationLink(destination: TutorialView(tutorial: item, feedData: feedData)) {
//                        TutorialUnitView(tutorial: item, feedData: feedData)
//                    }
//                }
                
                // for testing
                switch item.feedIdentity {
                case FeedIdentity.Article:
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(item.feedIdentity.rawValue + " " + item.id)) {
                        Text(item.feedIdentity.rawValue)
                    }
                case FeedIdentity.Tutorial:
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(item.feedIdentity.rawValue + " " + item.id)) {
                        Text(item.feedIdentity.rawValue)
                    }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! Great use of `switch` statement! I sitll have a problem, I guess it comes from `ForEach` loop.

Comment: This Error: "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

Comment: thanks it worked! Once I've made `ForEach(feedData.feed, id: \.id)`, with **id: \.id** it worked